# javascript active href attribute after first click on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to create `javascript` when first click on any `html` page part active link until not
or how to create body transparent layer when user first click on html page active link or any other HTML part

i need java script for html page 
one transparent layer on body HTML when user first click on any part html layer will remove and all other HTML part active until user can see full HTML but without without first click user can not click link flash etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="http://www.domain.com">
This is a link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question description was translated using google translate

Comment: sorry my English not much good

Comment: If you must use translate tools then use the simplest and least ambiguous language you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html create a div that's fixed position and 100% width and height

HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

JS

```
$('#overlay').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XbwYq/

Comment: i have update info please see

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkHandle = function() {return false;}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').bind('click', linkHandle);
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $('a').unbind('click', linkHandle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
     $(document).off("click");
     return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this is what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/ZXk9q/3/)

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

That is going to remove the anchor from the link once it has been clicked.

Comment: i have update info please see